# line level Mono audio input for led flasher

Tags: led

Looking for a super simple schematic for a line level mono input for a led flasher using batteries. Such as a trigger audio tone from a "whatever" source that turns an led on when the tone begins, and then off when the tone ends.

Comment: Look at my answer to this question:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77863/amplifying-an-audio-signal/77923#77923

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the IC [LM3916](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3916.pdf), which has been designed for this purpose.

It's very easy to use and it's cheap. All you will need is:

- the LM3916
- a 9v battery (just to keep things simple)
- the LEDs
- two resistors (to set the LEDs current, and sensibility of the circuit).

For an example circuit take a look at the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3916.pdf) at page 2, you can also find there the equations to specify the resistors.

If you want to diferentiate between tones, like a bass or a high pitch, you can build copies of the circuit and put a filter in the input of each one. But start with the simpler circuit.

Now go and get a breadboard and start prototyping :)